# EGMaps doesn’t load on renderPartial

Tags: ajax, yii, renderpartial

I’m triying to load an EGMap on a partial view. This is my code:

This is the ajax button which calls the action loadmap:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxsubmitButton ("Press for geolocation",
                              CController::createUrl('organization/loadmap'),
                              array('update' => '#formMap'));
```

The action loadmap:

```
$this->renderPartial('_loadMap',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
```

And finally the partial view:

```
$address = $model->address . ", " . City::model()->giveLocation($model->cityID);

        echo $address;

        Yii::import('ext.EGMap.*');

        $gMap = new EGMap();
        $gMap->zoom = 5;
        $gMap->width = '100%';
        $gMap->height = 200;

        $mapTypeControlOptions = array(
            'position'=> EGMapControlPosition::RIGHT_TOP,
            'style'=>EGMap::MAPTYPECONTROL_STYLE_DEFAULT,
        );

        $gMap->mapTypeId = EGMap::TYPE_HYBRID;

        $gMap->mapTypeControlOptions= $mapTypeControlOptions;

        // Create geocoded address
        $geocoded_address = new EGMapGeocodedAddress($address);
        $geocoded_address->geocode($gMap->getGMapClient());

        // Center the map on geocoded address
        $gMap->setCenter($geocoded_address->getLat(), $geocoded_address->getLng());

        // Add marker on geocoded address
        $gMap->addMarker(
            new EGMapMarker($geocoded_address->getLat(), $geocoded_address->getLng())
        );

        $gMap->renderMap();
```

The website loads the div but not the map. Any suggestion???

The firebug says: google is not defined

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: did it ever worked? i am having this issue now

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it would not work in `renderPartial` you would have to use `Iframe` and you can update its `src` on event. This worked out for me

Comment: can u provide me the src , how can we set marker on that by giving lattitude and longitude?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? change coordinates depending on some dropdown value? if you take `Iframe` you cant do that because of browsers do not allow that

Comment: yeah. i found another solution.